# Should I have waited before going to the land of the livid dead?

Tags: rayman-origins

I've been playing Rayman Origins for a while now, and yesterday I finally managed to collect all those red teeth that are scattered across the various game worlds, granting me access to the land of the livid dead.

Mind you, at this point I still did not finish all the levels in the Moody Clouds, but since getting the teeth was insanely difficult at times, I couldn't wait to see what the land of the livid dead was all about.

Turns out it was a set of the most challenging levels I've come across in the game, ending at an impressive boss monster. What surprised me, is that after defeating said boss it transformed to a character I've never seen before in the game, definitely not the main antagonist as portrayed by the game's intro, and I was then treated to the game's credits.

Should I have waited and gone to the land of the livid dead only after finishing with the Moody Clouds? Would it have made more sense then? Would I have even had the chance?

Comment: I assume you are referring to the big monster turning into a nymph?

Comment: That is precisely what I am referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From all that I remember, there is really no explanation for the nymph's appearance at the end of Land of the Livid. There is nothing in Moody Clouds that will explain it. From my understanding, the Land of the Livid is really just a truly optional second ending separate from the main story ending on Moody Clouds.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main antagonist in the intro is just another livid dead granny in the game.

The actual main antagonist is revealed at the end of the main game, I won't spoil it, but it's as random as you might expect.

The livid dead level and boss feels a bit tacked on, but then I guess only a relative few will beat it. Unlike every other boss (which are corrupted shrimps, flowers or whatever) and other fairies (which are saved in chase levels) the livid dead boss frees a goth fairy.

I don't think she has anything to do with the plot.